# Can't find "Global Variable view" in Katalon Studio

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, katalon-studio

I have read all the documents, all youtube videos and all GUI help guides, however I am not able to find "Global Variables view" in Katalon studio.
Here is a screenshot of my Katalon Studio installation.

[image]

Can someone guide me where to look for Global Variables view in Katalon Studio?

Comment: It's been moved to become 'default' profile of Execution Profile as you can see in Tests Explorer

Comment: Thanks. Found it. You should put your comment as answer rather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 5.4 (the one you are using), the global variables were replaced and are now managed via profiles. You can check them on the last item of the main tree.